# how to make array out of iterarted values in while loop

Tags: php, arrays

I have a variable in a while loop that is making dates. I want to get all the dates that are generated on each iteration of while loop into an array outside the while loop. Is this possible?

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sq))
    {
     extract($row);
     $startDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($created_on. ' + '.$days_for_start.' days'));
    $end_date   =   date("d-m-Y", strtotime($created_on. ' + '.$days_for_end.' days')); 
    } 

print_r($end_date);

//should output, 24-03-2017 for number of times the loop is running, in an array.
```

Comment: inside `while`  loop use this `$end_date[] = ...`

Comment: Use an array e.g. `$end_dates = [];` before loop and `$end_dates[] = date...` inside the loop then `print_r($end_dates)` outside the loop

Comment: Sorry,no success :( @SahilGulati

Answer (score 1):

```
$end_date = array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sq))
{
     extract($row);
     $startDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($created_on. ' + '.$days_for_start.' days'));
     $end_date[]  = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($created_on. ' + '.$days_for_end.' days')); 
} 

print_r($end_date);
```

updated one

// used `$end_date_tmp` variable as array.

```
$end_date_tmp = array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sq))
{
     extract($row);
     $startDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($created_on. ' + '.$days_for_start.' days'));
     $end_date_tmp[]  = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($created_on. ' + '.$days_for_end.' days')); 
} 

print_r($end_date_tmp);
```

Comment: Sorry but not working. Actually I cant take end_date into an array inside the while loop. is there any other fix?

Comment: share your code and data than might be I help you ...

Comment: Added the code.

Comment: where `$created_on` and `$days_for_start` comes from?

Comment: try upadted answer @Ansh. It should be `print_r($end_dates);` instead of `print_r($end_date);`

Comment: @Desai you are right thanks may be I m update this part.

Comment: @B.Desai I have used $end_date variable name everywhere. I dont think its gonna make any difference

Comment: @addy These are two values I am fetching from db

Comment: Then in while loop also use `$end_date[] ` instead of `$end_dates[]` @Ansh

Comment: check the updated code.

Comment: As soon as I am using $end_date[] = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($created_on. ' + '.$days_for_end.' days')); , my listing on page becomes empty.

Comment: @B.Desai I am using `$end_date` everywhere

Comment: Can we connect on email. I can post you the whole code so you can have a better insight. It will be a lifesaver to me @B.Desai

Comment: @addy Can we connect on email. I can post you the whole code so you can have a better insight. It will be a lifesaver to me

Comment: you can also put your code here (not need complete just a part of it) so any other one can help you also.

Comment: its a big and complex scripting in it. Posting here is not a problem but lot many things will not be of much use

Comment: can you share what the output of `$end_date` from your code and is there any error occurs when you use above code?

Comment: I have a list of chapters for which quiz has to be given. When using `$end_date[] = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($created_on. ' + '.$days_for_end.' days')); ` that whole list becomes empty

Comment: For me $end_date gives last iterated value of while loop. i.e. one date

Comment: and when my code used what the output of print_r.

Comment: print_r outputs nothing. As i said, only the chapter list becomes empty. Somewhere its breaking the code in while

Comment: maybe then the issue is with your execution try to use `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`  to get the error and share it back.

Comment: Shows Fatal error : [] not supported for strings.

Comment: then maybe you assign a string value to `$end_date` above in your code try the update part of the answer.then try to use `$end_date_tmp[index]` array as your `$end_date` variable